# Remove Saturdays (but not Sundays or other dataless periods) from Timeserie plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting a financial timeserie (see below, here 1 month worth of data)

[image]

I would like to remove the periods I show with red cross etc., which are Saturdays. Note that those periods are not all the time periods without data but only the Saturdays.

I know there are some example of how to remove the gaps , for instance: http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/date_index_formatter.html.
This is not what I am after since they remove all the gaps. (NOT MY INTENT!).

I was thinking that the way to go might be to create a custom sequence of values for the xaxis. Since the days are ordinals (ie 1 day = a value of 1), it might be possible to create a sequence such as 1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,15,16,etc. skipping 1 every seven days - that day skipped needing to be a Saturday of course.

The skipping of every Saturday i can imagine how to do it using rrule from timeutil. It is done here (see below) as every Monday is marked with a stronger vertical line. But How would i go at passing it to the Tick locator? There is in fact a RRuleLocator class in the matplotlib API but no indication on how to use it is given in the doc: http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.RRuleLocator. 
Every suggestion welcome.

Here the code that I use for the current chart:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, figsize=(20, 6))
quotes = price_data.as_matrix() # as matrix() to remove the columns header of the df
mpf.candlestick_ohlc(axes[0], quotes, width=0.01) 
plt.bar(quotes[:,0] , quotes[:,5], width = 0.01)
for i , axes[i] in enumerate(axes):
    axes[i].xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=1) )
    axes[i].xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%a, %b %d'))
    axes[i].grid(True)

    # show night times with a grey shade
    majors=axes[i].xaxis.get_majorticklocs()
    chart_start, chart_end = (axes[i].xaxis.get_view_interval()[0], 
                              axes[i].xaxis.get_view_interval()[1])
    for major in majors:
        axes[i].axvspan(max (chart_start, major-(0.3333)),
                        min(chart_end, major+(0.3333)),color="0.95", zorder=-1 ) #0.33 corresponds to 1/3 of a day i.e. 8h

    # show mondays with a line
    mondays = list(rrule(WEEKLY, byweekday=MO, dtstart= mdates.num2date(chart_start),
               until=mdates.num2date(chart_end)))
    for j, monday in enumerate(mondays):
        axes[i].axvline(mdates.date2num(mondays[j]), linewidth=0.75, color='k', zorder=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your dates are `datetime` objects, or a `DateTimeIndex` in a `pandas` `DataFrame`, you could check which weekday a certain date is using `.weekday`. Then you just set the data on Saturdays to `nan`. See the example below.

## Code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import random
import datetime
import numpy as np

# generate some data with a datetime index
x = 400
data = pd.DataFrame([
    random.random() for i in range(x)],
    index=[datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 0)
           + datetime.timedelta(hours=i) for i in range(x)])
# Set all data on a Saturday (5) to nan, so it doesn't show in the graph           
data[data.index.weekday == 5] = np.nan

# Plot the data
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 2.5))
ax.plot(data)

# Set a major tick on each weekday
days = mdates.DayLocator()
daysFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%a')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(days)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(daysFmt)
```

## Result

[image]

Comment: OP wants to  "remove the periods I show with red cross". your plot still has it.

Comment: That is correct.I don't know how to solve that yet.